# Closing UIActionSheet

Tags: ios

I have a UIActionSheet and I have added the following - UIPickerView and 2 BarButtonItems. I am trying to close the action sheet when someone clicks the Cancel Button (it is one of the bar button items).

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
[actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0,40,0,0);
UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
pickerView.dataSource = self;
pickerView.delegate = self;

[actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
UIToolbar *tools = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
tools.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[actionSheet addSubview:tools];

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(btnActinDoneClicked)];
doneButton.imageInsets=UIEdgeInsetsMake(200, 6, 50, 25);
UIBarButtonItem *CancelButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(btnActinCancelClicked)]; //this is where the problem is

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:CancelButton, doneButton, nil];
[tools setItems:array];

[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
```

I have added another method to dismiss the action sheet -

```
-(IBAction)btnActinCancelClicked:(id)sender{
    [sender dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is that the app crashes when the BarButton is clicked. I think the problem is caused where the CancelButton is declared and it is unable to send a message to the btnActinCancelClicked method, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your console output when your app crashes?

Comment: This is the error message - *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIActionSheet btnActinCancelClicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68a5bd0'

Comment: Check my answer as to why you are getting that exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is this;

```
-(IBAction)btnActinCancelClicked:(id)sender
```

So you need to add it like this (because it receives a parameter);

```
@selector(btnActinCancelClicked:)
```

So for example, if a method had three parameters you'd call it `@selector(myMethod:andX:andY:)`

Also, to access your UIActionSheet (not entirely sure this will work);

```
UIActionSheet *acSheet = sender.superView;

//Check if it is the ActionSheet here then dismiss it

[acSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: I tried declaring UIActionSheet *actionSheet in the .h file, but same problem

Answer (score 1):

It's not the sender you want to dismiss. It's the ActionSheet. You'll need a reference for that and change your code for something like:

```
- (IBAction)btnActinCancelClicked:(id)sender{
    [self.actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```